# React custom hooks: returning a ref from hook vs passing the ref as hooks argument

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-ref

Consider I have a custom hook that uses one or more `refs` to DOM elements, I see two distinct ways how to write/use a hook like that (and I know there are probably even more nuances – e. g. callback refs).

**Option 1**: return a `ref` from custom hook and use it in a component:

```
const Option1 = () => {
  const hooksRef = myCustomHookReturninARef()
  
  return <div ref={hooksRef}>Using returned ref as prop.</div>
}
```

**Option 2**: create a `ref` in a component and pass it to a custom hook:

```
const Option2 = () => {
  const componentsRef = React.createRef()
  
  myCustomHookExpectingRefArgument(componentsRef)
  
  return <div ref={componentsRef}>Using created ref as prop..</div>
}
```

I've been using either options and they both seems to be working fine. I know this is likely an *opinionated question*, but:

**Are there some significant drawbacks using the first vs the second approach?**

Comment: I came here because I myself have the same dilemma :-)

Answer (score 2):

I came here because I myself have the same dilemma :-).  My 2 cents:

- The hook user can be made more concise if the hook returns the ref since don't have to create it.
- On the other hand, if the user already have a ref from a different ref-returning hook, they might have to combine two different refs.  While that's maybe a straightforward task, it certainly tripped me up when I was in that situation.

Maybe one could get the best of both worlds, by both receiving and returning a ref?  If the hook *doesn't* get a ref then it simply creates one. Either way it can return the ref.

Answer (score 0):

not an React virtuoso, but from my perspective the only drawback using `Option1` is that you have to validate the returned value to be a `ref`, from computing perspective there is no difference

Comment: Thanks for your insight, that from a computing perspective, there is no difference. Since I am not a "React virtuoso" as well, I rather aim to avoid possible future footguns. Cheers!